# Why isn't my form data getting to my @RequestBody

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring. I have a controller that creates a page for the user, who then enters data. I need to capture that data and put in a database
My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/pdc"})
public class PDCController {
    // generate page to send to user
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/{ffaAssgnId}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAssignment(Model model, @PathVariable Integer ffaAssgnId) {
        Integer userContactId = userService.getUserContactId();

        PDCAssgn assignment = pdcService.getAssgn(ffaAssgnId, userContactId);

        List<MagValidate> statuses = validateService.getValidateByType("FAS");
        Map<Integer, MagValidate> mapStatuses = new HashMap<>();
        for (MagValidate status : statuses) {
            mapStatuses.put(status.getValidateId(), status);
        }

        model.addAttribute("mapStatus", mapStatuses);
        model.addAttribute("assignment", assignment);

        return "pdc";
    }
    // get response from user
    @RequestMapping(value = {""}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody AjaxResponse updateAssignment(@RequestBody PDCAssgn assignment) {
        System.out.println(assignment.toString());

//      try {
//          pdcService.updateAssgn(assignment);
//      } catch (Exception ex) {
//          ex.printStackTrace();
//          List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
//          errors.add("Error saving DARF.");
//          return new AjaxResponse("ERROR", null, errors);
//      }

        return new AjaxResponse("OK", null, null);
    }
}
```

Part of my rendered form

```
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues0.assgnIssue.promoDealers" name="wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.promoDealers" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues0.assgnIssue.dealersFound" name="wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.dealersFound" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues0.assgnIssue.curDraw" name="wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.curDraw" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues1.assgnIssue.promoDealers" name="wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.promoDealers" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues1.assgnIssue.dealersFound" name="wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.dealersFound" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
    <td><input id="wholesalerIssues1.assgnIssue.curDraw" name="wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.curDraw" class="numberLarge" type="text" value=""/></td>
```

Equivalent jsp

```
    <td><form:input  path="wholesalerIssues[${whStatus.index}].assgnIssue.promoDealers" cssClass="numberLarge" placeholder="${targetTitle.promoDealers}"/></td>
    <td><form:input  path="wholesalerIssues[${whStatus.index}].assgnIssue.dealersFound" cssClass="numberLarge" placeholder="${targetTitle.dealersFound}"/></td>
    <td><form:input  path="wholesalerIssues[${whStatus.index}].assgnIssue.curDraw" cssClass="numberLarge" placeholder="${targetTitle.curDraw}"/></td>
```

The javascript to send the data

```
function doSendA(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var form = $("#frm-assignment");
var formFields = $("#frm-assignment input:not([readonly])")
var formData = {}
$.each(formFields, function(i, v){
    var input = $(v);
    // populate form data as key-value pairs
    // with the name of input as key and its value as value
    formData[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
});
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdc",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ,
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(ajaxResponse) {
        if (ajaxResponse.status !== "OK") {
            hideLoading();
            showToast("bad", ajaxResponse.errors[0]);
            return;
        }
        hideLoading();
//              location.reload();
            showToast("good", "Your data was saved.");
    },
    error : function(res) {
        hideLoading();
        showToast("bad", "There was a problem saving your data.");
    }
});
}
```

The `console.log(formData);`

```
{"wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.promoDealers":"123","wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.dealersFound":"","wholesalerIssues[0].assgnIssue.curDraw":"","wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.promoDealers":"","wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.dealersFound":"","wholesalerIssues[1].assgnIssue.curDraw":""}
```

The controller's `System.out.println(assignment.toString());`

```
magforce.model.PDCAssgn@4f71f251[wholesalerIssues=<null>]
```

I played around with printing out things from the request and found that there were no errors during the binding, but my resultant data object remains empty. I have done many Google queries, but haven't yet found anything that uses Spring's form tags (`<form:form>` , `<form:input>`, etc.) plus ajax json and Spring's @RequestBody.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your endpoint using curl or Postman or something like that?

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel No. I'm not sure how I would do that. Currently I believe that it has to do with the code that assembles the `formData`. I am currently working on a function that builds a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, but putting it here as an expansion to my comment. The goal here is to show you how you could test your endpont.

Your controller is exposing an endpoint. If you start up your application you have a URL you can access, in this case at "http://localhost:8080/pdc" (unless you are prefixing your URL, but based on what your are posting this should be your URL). If you are on a *NIX system you have curl at your disposal. If you are on Windows you might want to give Postman a try. To use curl on your POST endpoint, a call to your endpoint would be something like this. Of course I don't know your object structure so make sure to adjust the JSON according to the structure of your object.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          -X POST -d \
       '{
           "yourObject":{
              "someArray":[
                 {
                     "aDate":{
                        "year":2019,
                        "month":10,
                        "day":1
                     },
                    "someValue":4,
                    "otherVaule":10000,
                    "anId":1
                 }
              ],
              "someOtherValue":100000,
              "someStatus":"DRAFT"
           }
        }' http://localhost:8080/pdc
```

By testing your endpoint using a tool like this you can isolate the problem you are having. Once you have a successful cal to your endpoint you will at least know that your endpoint is in order and that any problems will lie in your JavaScript code.

Comment: I have Postman up and running and I've tried calling the endpoint with the json object, but I am getting a missing CSRF token. I've tried copying the token in the page that I've just loaded, but the system says it is invalid, which I assume is the point of the token. I'm not sure how to bypass the token.

Comment: Ah, you're getting closer. The fact that you need a CSRF token is probably also the reason why your call from JavaScript is failing. Do you happen to have Spring Security enabled?

Comment: Yes. We have a log in page that the user is directed to when they try to access anything in the system. I probably need to get through that, so I'd need a session id.

Comment: Yes, it's Spring Security that's blocking you here. You will also need to add the CSRF token to your requests. This is a good page to get started on the CSRF topic in combination with Spring Security: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf